# what are the APIs available in java for drawing animations or static digrams?

Tags: java, graphics, portability

Is `Java 2D API` is the only available for drawing in Java? What are other options available? 
What are the advantages or disadvantages of using an external drawing tool like `dotty`.

Comment: Best is a very relative term.  What are you drawling?

Comment: sorry I am late. Just starting to do the work which required drawing. I want to draw basic shapes like: few types of arrows, few ovals and circles and squares and  rectangles.It is like a modified version of state charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Apache ImageLoader API](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/commons/image-loader.html) if you want to manipulate images.